# Center button in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I just want to center "CenterButton" (center of the root LinearLayout) but Androids just not cooperating..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#zegerg"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/image_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abcdef"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/CenterButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text !"
            android:id="@+id/TextView"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:textColor="#37a52c" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:progressTint="#37a52c" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_text"
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Tried putting it at the end of the XML but doesn't work because the other elements push it aside.. not really sure what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have all three first level children to be in equally-sized columns, then you need to add to all of them the followings attribute:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

(don't forget the dimension "dp" to the width parameter, otherwise the IDE will complain).

```
...
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:src="@mipmap/image_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abcdef"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/CenterButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">
....
```

**EDITED:**
If you want your CenterButton to overlap all the other views, then what you have to do is:

1. wrap everything in a relative layout with height equal to 200dp, as its first child
2. remove the button *CenterButton* from the current position and add it at the bottom of everything, still inside the relative layout, but below the linear layout
3. add those properties to the button to make it center in the parent

android:layout_centerInParent="true"

So finally you will have something like this (I have changed some resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:contentDescription="abcdef"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text !"
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:textColor="#37a52c" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:progressTint="#37a52c" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/CenterButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I actually didn't mention in my question that the button should be on top of the rest. Like an overlapse. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: can you make a mock-up/drawing on paper of how do you want to make it looks like?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xkUKh.png I tried making a new question but theres a 1,5h limit.

Comment: ahhh but then it is even more easier to do, I will edit my answer in a sec

Comment: Please see my edited answer above :-) That is the simplest thing that you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) for such purposes for child items. Make **layout_width** for all of them as **0dp** and set **layout_weight** as **1**.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that it should be ON TOP of the other items but that's another quesion now..

Answer (score 0):

Give the three children in the topmost linear layout a gravity of 1 and a width of 0.

Comment: A gravity of 1? How is that possible?

Comment: android:layout_gravity=1
Or do it in the designer window.

Comment: Oh layout_gravity, I was confused with just "gravity"

Comment: It's impossible to input numbers for me.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="1"

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly is your problem. However, here are some general notes :

- To center a View or a Layout inside **RelativeView** use **layout_centerInParent="true"**
- To make a Layout on top of other layouts use **FrameLayout**
- The order of the views/layouts in your xml file is important. The one you write the last will be on the top (in our example : the FrameLayout or just the CenterButton should be written after the other views and layouts in your xml file)
- To distribute the available space inside **LinearLayout** among its views use  **android:layout_weight="1"** (change the value according to your needs)

you can play aground with this example :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:text="Text !"
                android:textColor="#37a52c" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:progressTint="#37a52c" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CenterButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```